# RAID 1 (mirror) - how a drive corresponds to a certain SATA port

Tags: raid

I want to build 2 systems (1 x Linux box, with a lot of space, RAID 1 mirrored)
and 1 x Win7 workstation for my graphic / music / video works, with RAID 1 as well.

Suppose one of the hdd fails at some point.

How do I know which SATA port / HDD drive to disconnect from the internal case ?

Is there a way that the Linux or Win7 Raid software will tell you which one to get out of the case ?

I know there are some cases with led indic

Comment: As this is a home situation question, you'll find a lot more willing eyes on SuperUser.

Comment: thanx bro...i'll ask there as well

Comment: if anyone feels that it's the wrong place to ask this here, he/she can delete the post since i've moved it to SuperUser portal. If you all feel it's a good and valid question that might be answered by people around here too, just leave it here as well.

Comment: For future reference: A couple more close votes would have automatically migrated the question to the sister site. I'll flag this one for deletion.